# Joining query Result with another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following query

```
Select TA.Column1 , COALESCE(TE.Column2,TA.Column2) as  Mydata

from TableA TA
INNER JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.Column2 =TB.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableC TC ON (TB.Column2  = TC.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableD TD ON (TC.Column1 = TD.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableE TE ON(TD.Column2 = TE.Column1)
```

To get the result I am looking for I need to `Join` the `MyData` column with another `TableX`

e.g `INNER JOIN TableX TX ON (TableX.Column1 = MyData)` and have `TableX.COlumn2` in my select query .

My query is how can I join the `COALESCE(TE.Column2,TA.Column2) as  Mydata` fetched value with a table `TableX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the surface, you should be able to do this.  (Did you try that already?)

```
Select TA.Column1 , COALESCE(TE.Column2,TA.Column2) as  Mydata, TX.Column2
from TableA TA
INNER JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.Column2 =TB.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableC TC ON (TB.Column2  = TC.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableD TD ON (TC.Column1 = TD.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableE TE ON(TD.Column2 = TE.Column1)
LEFT JOIN TableX TX ON (COALESCE(TE.Column2,TA.Column2)) = TX.Column1
```